# how plot error bars with grouped dataset in R

Tags: r

[1]I know it is basic in R, but as a new learner in R I have struggle still.
I have a dataset including 550 ID, each ID include 100 value for variable x, so it has 55000 rows (each ID repeated 100 times). NOW I need to see variability in the data across all 600 IDs. I tried error bars with the difference between 2.5 and 97.5 percentile. but it plot 55000, ,while I need just 550 error bars.
Does anyone have this issue?

```r
 ggplot(CC, aes(x= CatchID, y= SMSC_mm))+
    geom_point(color="pink", size=.1)+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= percentile_2.5, ymax= percentile_97.5), width=2, color="blue")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=.0001, size =2))
``
edited code:
ggplot(CC) +
  geom_point(aes(x= CatchID, y= SMSC_mm, color ="lightblue"), size=1.1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x= CatchID, y= SMSC_mm, ymin = percentile_2.5, ymax = percentile_97.5),color="darkgrey", width = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x= CatchID, y = median,color= "blue")) +
  geom_point(aes(x= CatchID, y = mean_SMSC_mm, color="red")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(lightblue = "lightblue", blue = "blue", red = "red"),
   labels = c(lightblue = "SMSC_mm", blue = "median", red = "mean_SMSC_mm")) +
  labs(y = "SMSC (mm) for 100 parameter sets per CatchID", x= "CatchID") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.0001, size = 7), 
        legend.justification = c(1,1), 
        legend.direction = "vertical")][2]
[this is a plot of my data based on edited code, and the blue line map is from Edward's code:

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XgQ9.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo69L.jpg
```

Comment: hello Mary, welcome to SO, can you include a `dput()` of your GP data in the question so we can reproduce this issue and help? run `dput(GP)` and include it in your question.

Comment: Hi Jeffreyohene, I've done the dput(), but as my data is a big (55000rows), I just get a summary() in my question. 
just let you know that my data is CC, I edited the names in my code.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create the data frame for the error bars first, and then supply this to the `geom_errorbar` function. Simulated data appears below.

```
library(ggplot2)

error_bars <- group_by(GP, ID) %>%
  summarise(percentile_2.5=quantile(SMSC, probs=0.25),
            percentile_97.5=quantile(SMSC, probs=0.75))

ggplot(GP, aes(x= ID)) +
  geom_point(aes(y= SMSC), color="pink", size=.1) +
  geom_errorbar(data=error_bars,
                aes(ymin= percentile_2.5, ymax= percentile_97.5), width=2, color="blue")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=.0001, size =10)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

### [image]

**Data**:

```
set.seed(1234)
GP <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:550, 100), SMSC=rnorm(55000))
```

Comment: Hi Edward, thanks for your time. I've run your code. it is great. I also tried alot and finally create this plot which looks different from yours. (I've attached both ).I don't know I did right way or not. so, it is my new code, could you please have a look at on. I don't understand why two plots are different, while data is the same. Thanks.

Comment: Your plot looks ok but your code is different (you need a new data aes in the errorbars function). The data is also not the same since while yours is on your computer and you didn't upload it here, I simulated mine.